# Issue in inoke-webrequest to update my chromecast firmware

Tags: powershell, chromecast, invoke-webrequest

I need to update firmware of my chromecast but I have restriction on my internet and then I cannot update it automatically. I need to update it by pc while I am using vpn. Therefore, I am using following script in powershell. However, the code run successfully but there is no result.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body '{"params": "ota foreground"}' -
Uri "http://<my chrom IP>:8008/setup/reboot" -Verbose -UserAgent "curl"
```

Here is result of running that script:

```
VERBOSE: POST http://<my chrom IP>:8008/setup/reboot with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 0-byte response of content type


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
                    Content-Length: 0
                    Cache-Control: no-cache


Headers           : {[Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type], [Content-Length, 0], [Cache-Control, no-cache]}
RawContentLength  : 0
```